# Grabbing a window from screen in Windows 10 in Python

Tags: python, window

Right now I'm grabbing the full screen resolution of a window in windows 10, followed by using cv2.matchTemplate and a template of the screen I cut from paint for example. It works. But I was thinking that there must be some kind of command to just grab a screen from a specific window, or is my assumption wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: That is likely to be platform-specific, because it is about enumerating displayed windows to find the one you want. So, what platform?

Comment: windows 10, sorry, I'll put it in the text thanks.